# Image not set on UIWebview from reference folder(blue folder)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When i am trying to load an image on UIWebView from reference folder it shows a small blue question mark my code is:

```
NSString *imagePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataResources/IMG_0878.jpg"];

[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"file://%@\"/>",imagePath] baseURL:nil];
```

and also when i am using the same to load an image on UIImageView then it works perfectly

code for setting an image is :

```
UIImage *tile = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"dataResources/IMG_0878.jpg")];

[imgv setImage:tile];
```

please suggest me how can i resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

may be your HTML string is wrong. use this

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_0878" ofType:@"jpg"];
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",path] baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: HTML string is wright but thanks for the answer actually i found where the problem is we can't show the image format like .jpg and .png on web view we can shoe only .gif image format and also if we want to show the .jpg and .png format then we have to pass the server URL/path instead of local resource path.

Comment: good, would suggest you post it as an answer, so that others can refer.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_0878" ofType:@"jpg"];    

NSURL *bundleUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];

[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"file://%@\"/>",imagePath] baseURL:bundleUrl];
```

You didn't set bundleUrl